# PHP - segfault in appending element to array

Tags: php, arrays, segmentation-fault

I have an array containing about 75 elements (not very deeply nested).
When I try to add a new element with:

```
$myArray['mykey'][] = $newElement;
```

I get a segfault with php error 4.
Is there a way to prevent from it? how can I change this code to avoid such things. Tried array_merge, array_unshift or += operation - all with the same result

**Edit:**

Sorry, here are details: PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14, Ubuntu 14.04 x64. Application also usess RabbitMQ, Redis, Elasticsearch

```
    public function modify($stock, $new) {

    if (!isset($stock['data_sets'])) {
        $stock['data_sets'] = []; 
    }

    $stock['data_sets'][]= $new;

    if (!isset($stock['garbage_sets'])) {
        $stock['garbage_sets'] = [];
    }

    return $stock;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you show a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for reproduce the problem? What OS and PHP version and build are you use?

Comment: We need more details...

Comment: What PHP version, what is `echo memory_get_peak_usage(true);`, please give more context and details.

Comment: Segfault almost always means a bug (either in PHP itself or in a third-party library). Your alternatives are upgrading to another version or tweaking your dataset until you're lucky enough to not have the bug triggered. However, it feels weird that you've hit a bug in such simple code. Are you sure this is all?

Comment: Sorry, here are details: PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14, Ubuntu 14.04 x64. Application also usess RabbitMQ, Redis, Elasticsearch

Comment: The **code** is required. Álvaro is right, segfault is a bug, but no one helps you without the code that caused this segfault. Obviously, code that you provide does not produce any fatal error in the any PHP version (really: https://3v4l.org/9bfNe)